# Send data to API containing special characters

Tags: bash, rest, ubuntu, curl

I am trying to send JSON data containing a mac address to an api using this command:

```
$value={ "pcModel": "KAT12", "displayType": "DELL U2311H", "graphicsType": "Microsoft Remote Display Adapter", "displayServiceTag": "HV8XP08Q079L", "ipAddress": "172.16.4.194", "recDate": "2022-10-06 16:57:55", "serviceTag": "18LQ9X1;Diskwear:(4.91TBW ; 15393 Hours)", "wolMode": "lanwithpxeboot;CC:101010-0118ZH;os:Ubuntu", "sleepState": "disable", "macAddress": "90:B1:1C:8E:D5:11", "hostName": "CI-KR95-05", "diskMode": "raid", "diskType": "Samsung SSD 850 PRO 512GB;TBW+Hrs:(4.91TB;15393 HrH) ;Clock:3.4GHz;Max Clock:3.67GHz(108%);RAM:32GB" }

curl -X "PUT" -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Authorization: Token 62d85330rf562c4cd6c1fb1a64d1" -d "$value" --url "https://my_api.org/api/inventory/84:2b:2b:a0:0s2:18
```

but I get the following answer:

```
user@ubuntu:~$ curl -X "PUT" -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Authorization: Token 62d85df90210cd1a827bc1518c4cd6c1fb1a64d1" -d "$value" --url "https:/my_api/api/inventory/84:2b:2b:a0:0s2:18"

curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL
```

I tried to escape the ":" colon characters with \ like this

```
curl -X "PUT" -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Authorization: Token 62d85330rf562c4cd6c1fb1a64d1" -d "$value" --url "https://my_api.org/api/inventory/84\:2b\:2b\:a0\:0s\:18"
```

but I get no output and it sends nothing.

any Idea how to send this data without having the bad format error?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Put a valid shebang in your code and paste it at https://shellcheck.net for validation/recommendations.

Comment: Define your shell variable (containing JSON) as follows: `value='{ "pcModel": "KAT12", ... }'`, i.e. no dollar sign and the whole JSON within single quotes.

Answer (score 1):

I removed the "?" from $value and added single quotes.
**Try this:**

```
#!/bin/bash
value='{ "pcModel": "KAT12", "displayType": "DELL U2311H", "graphicsType": "Microsoft Remote Display Adapter", "displayServiceTag": "HV8XP08Q079L", "ipAddress": "172.16.4.194", "recDate": "2022-10-06 16:57:55", "serviceTag": "18LQ9X1;Diskwear:(4.91TBW ; 15393 Hours)", "wolMode": "lanwithpxeboot;CC:101010-0118ZH;os:Ubuntu", "sleepState": "disable", "macAddress": "90:B1:1C:8E:D5:11", "hostName": "CI-KR95-05", "diskMode": "raid", "diskType": "Samsung SSD 850 PRO 512GB;TBW+Hrs:(4.91TB;15393 HrH) ;Clock:3.4GHz;Max Clock:3.67GHz(108%);RAM:32GB" }'
curl -X "PUT" -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Authorization: Token 62d85330rf562c4cd6c1fb1a64d1" -d "$value" --url "https://my_api.org/api/inventory/84:2b:2b:a0:0s2:18"
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, actually there was something missing also, I needed to add "Content-Type: application/json" to tell the API to take the data as JSON, because apparently application/json is not enough. Ill modify your answer and mark it as correct. Actually there is an issue editing your answer, because the "editing queue is full". Ill answer my own question. But thanks

Answer (score 1):

Didn't your mother teach you how to format?

```
value='{
  "pcModel": "KAT12",
  "displayType": "DELL U2311H",
  "graphicsType": "Microsoft Remote Display Adapter",
  "displayServiceTag": "HV8XP08Q079L",
  "ipAddress": "172.16.4.194",
  "recDate": "2022-10-06 16:57:55",
  "serviceTag": "18LQ9X1;Diskwear:(4.91TBW ; 15393 Hours)",
  "wolMode": "lanwithpxeboot;CC:101010-0118ZH;os:Ubuntu",
  "sleepState": "disable",
  "macAddress": "90:B1:1C:8E:D5:11",
  "hostName": "CI-KR95-05",
  "diskMode": "raid",
  "diskType": "Samsung SSD 850 PRO 512GB;TBW+Hrs:(4.91TB;15393 HrH) ;Clock:3.4GHz;Max Clock:3.67GHz(108%);RAM:32GB"
}'
```

`$value` is not a legal variable name in bash for declaration, only when you want to look it up. use `value=`

Also, you are missing a `"` after the URL.

```
$ curl "http:/cake.com/nom-nom
> "
curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL
```

The protocol schema is followed by colon-slash-slash `://`. so you need one more:

```
https://
```

Maybe you want to read the URL rfc:

https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2718.txt

> 2.1.2 Improper use of "//" following ":"
>
> Contrary to some examples set in past years, the use of double
> slashes as the first component of the  of a URL
> is not simply an artistic indicator that what follows is a URL:
> Double slashes are used ONLY when the syntax of the URL's  contains a hierarchical structure as described in RFC
> 2396.  In URLs from such schemes, the use of double slashes indicates    that what follows is the top hierarchical element for a
> naming    authority.  (See section 3 of RFC 2396 for more details.)
> URL    schemes which do not contain a conformant hierarchical
> structure in    their  should not use double
> slashes following    the ":" string.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Actually the JSON's format is correct when you change it like you said --> value = '{"abc":"def","ghi":"jkl"}', the URL was not missing the end ", but I forgot to copy it in the example I sent. I put the working code below

Comment: there was nothing wrong with the json, I was just attempting a joke.

Comment: Yes i know, jokes are sometimes easier person to person, but thanks for taking the time to answer :).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers.

I found the reasons why my code was not updating the API

1 - I needed to specify the `"Content-Type: "application/json"` parameter to tell the API that the data sent hat JSON format otherwise I saw in verbose mode that the data has a "x-www-form-urlencoded" format that the API can't understand.

2 - The data sent with curl must accept a value with the format like this

```
value='{
  "pcModel": "KAT12",
  "displayType": "DELL U2311H",
  "diskType": "Samsung SSD .."
}'
```

3 - The curl request must be sent with double quotes around the url and the data `""`
So the end request looks like this:

```
curl -k -X "PUT" -H "Content-Type: application/json"\ 
-H "Accept: application/json" -H "Authorization: Token 62d85df902101828g84kc4cd6c1fb1a64d1" \
--url "https://my_api.org/api/inventory/84:2b:2b:a0:0s2:18" \
-d "$value"
```